# Restarting MongoDB on a non default port

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

how do I restart mongodb service in Ubuntu for a mongo instance running on a non-default port, ex. 27018?

'sudo service mongodb restart' doesnt seem to allow port parameter to specify a port.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start/run mongodb as a service on another port:

1) `sudo service mongod stop`

2)
add this in the config file `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
net:
   port: 27018
```

3) `sudo service mongod start`